# Assitive touch on React native or expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to develop and app using react native/expo just like the assistive touch , I have searched many RN forums but couldn't find any relevant thing regarding to the Assistive touch. the Assistive touch will have only 3 features Home , Back and Menu.
I have read article on https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/accessibility but didn't find it useful and handy. I need any recommendation of how to make it , is there any example on github